# Update particular row in tableviewcell in tableview in swift 3?

Tags: uitableview, swift3, xib, nsindexpath

I am using tableviewcell.xib in table view. In that I have comment button, if I click on that I will navigate to another page so that I can comment, when I dismiss after commenting. It will come to tableview page, in that I want to update the comment count value without updating with service call . where I should add this code for updating cell.Please help me.

```
     let indexPath = IndexPath(item: sender.tag, section: 0)  
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

I am navigating like this

```
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let commentPage = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postCommentsPage") as! PostCommentViewController
    self.present(commentPage, animated: false, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Edit your question with how you are moving to this comment screen. Also have you changed your datasource because if you haven't then reloading rows do nothing.?

Comment: I have also asked about your datasource array have you changed that too ?

Comment: @NiravD . I am not understanding what ur asking . I am not changing anything in datasource

Comment: You are showing data in tableView with array have you changed in that array to show new comment number other wise if you reload the row it will do nothing

Comment: @NiravD You are saying to update complete array if i am in my 10th post means need to update continuously

Comment: No You need to update a single object of array for that you are adding new comment

Comment: you can use a delegate to update tableview in another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to make one `protocol` like `UpdateCommentCount` and implement that protocol with your Controller where you are having this `tableView` after that in your `PostCommentViewController` make one instance property of type `UpdateCommentCount`, also in your tableController declare one property of type `Int` to hold the reference of tapped row.

```
protocol UpdateCommentCount {
    func updateComment(with count:Int)
}
```

Now implement this `UpdateCommentCount` with yourController and add one `Int` property to hold the reference of tapped row and set it inside your button action where you are presenting your `PostCommentViewController`

```
class YourController: UIViewController, UpdateCommentCount, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var currentCommentRow = 0

    //Your other methods

    func commentButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        currentCommentRow = sender.tag
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let commentPage = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postCommentsPage") as! PostCommentViewController
        commentPage.commentDelegate = self
        self.present(commentPage, animated: false, completion:nil)
    }

    func updateComment(with count:Int) {
        let dic = yourArray[self.currentCommentRow]
        dic["commentCount"] = count
        yourArray[self.currentCommentRow] = dic
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.currentCommentRow, section: 0)  
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
```

Now in `PostCommentViewController` declare one instance property named `commentDelegate` of type `UpdateCommentCount` and after simply call its delegate method when you successfully post comment.

```
var commentDelegate: UpdateCommentCount
```

Call `updateComment` after successfully posting new comment.

```
commentDelegate.updateComment(with: newCount)
```

Comment: When i scroll tableview the value is reverting back not showing updated value

Comment: @UmaMadhavi Have you changed the value in array also, if value is properly changed in array then this should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification. Register the notification in that table view's viewDidLoad method. Than send notification before presenting the view as shown bellow..

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let commentPage = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "postCommentsPage") as! PostCommentViewController
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: myNotificationKey), object: self)
    self.present(commentPage, animated: false, completion:nil)
```

Than reload table view in notification calling function.